# How to detect no of camera's available in android device? and also if the device has front camera how to use it?

Tags: android

How to detect no of camera's available in android device? and also if the device has front camera how to use it?

Answer (score 41):

What I would suggest is similar to doc_180's answer, but should be able to detect both front and back facing cameras even for Froyo, though if I'm not mistaken, Froyo never supported front-facing cameras, so you'll always get a false response for `frontCam` on Froyo.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean frontCam, rearCam;

//Must have a targetSdk >= 9 defined in the AndroidManifest
frontCam = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT);
rearCam = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

EDIT: Just realized this is a really, really old question. Oh well, hopefully it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can compile your app using Android 2.3 or higher and still make it compatible with Android 2.2. Remember that constants like `PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT` are actually hardcoded by the compiler, so it will not fail at runtime on Android 2.2 or older.

Answer (score 5):

Use packagemanager to check if the device supports the Intent. In this case `Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`);

```
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Comment by user without comment privileges ([profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1005899/cfg)): `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` doesn't work, you should use `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {              

        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply but i am using android 2.2 i don't find CameraInfo class. what to do now?

Comment: @suresh - Can you ask the user to tell the application if there is a front camera in the device or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I've found to check if a (backfacing) camera exists is to check if Camera.open() returns null.

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
if(null == cam){
   //no camera exists
}
```

This should be available for earlier versions of android as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this static method if you just want to know how many cameras there are:
Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); (api 9)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return false for devices with no rear camera like the Nexus 7.

Comment: Should try FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY instead.

Comment: FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY is the right way to go, but it works only on API 17 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method to get the count of the available camera

```
 public int getCameraCount(){
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String[] strings = manager.getCameraIdList();
        return strings.length;
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this worked for me in a Moto RAZR HD:

```
public static Camera open (int cameraId)
```

Example usage:

```
mCamera = Camera.open(1);
```

Comment: how on earth does that answer the question?