# Android front camera

Tags: android, camera

I need ONE function to check if front camera exist, and if so - show preview.
I found a few links, but each of them talk about a specific device:

- [How do I open the "front camera" on the Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int
- [Front-facing camera on LG Optimus 2X Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673725/front-facing-camera-on-lg-optimus-2x-speed)
- [How to use Front Facing Camera on Samsung Galaxy S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241292/how-to-use-front-facing-camera-on-samsung-galaxy-s)

Can anyone provide a generic code for this? Or maybe a combined code that will work with all devices?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**For APIs >=9**, you can use the `Camera` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html to see if it has more than one camera, and query the `CameraInfo`

- `getNumberOfCameras`
- `getCameraInfo`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html

> Constants
>
> int  CAMERA_FACING_BACK  The facing of the camera is opposite to that of the screen.
>
> int  CAMERA_FACING_FRONT     The facing of the camera is the same as that of the screen.

---

**For APIs >=5**, an option is to read `public List<Camera.Size> getSupportedPictureSizes ()`. Front facing cameras will usually have much lower max resolution than back cameras.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Answer (score 11):

This was posted by [kcoppock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8300396/1657308), but I figured someome will come across this message as well sometime. I tested it personally, worked great on Froyo.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean frontCam, rearCam;

//It would be safer to use the constant PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT
//but since it is not defined for Android 2.2, I substituted the literal value
frontCam = pm.hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.front");

rearCam = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

Comment: Nice tip. You can also use a constant for the front camera instead of hard code the value. That is PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT

Answer (score 2):

in 2.3 it is possible. http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/9/changes/android.hardware.Camera.html

But before that, Android sdk did not have any generic api for finding and using the second front camera.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can loop through the available cameras on the phone and check the [facing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#facing) camera info to find one (but it is only available sing API level 9)

this answer could help you: [How do I open the "front camera" on the Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform/4767832#4767832)