# Looking to make an Android app that uses only front camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to create an app where it uses the front camera only for 2.2 and above. I can't find a tutorial anywhere. Can someone help. I also want to know if one can adjust the view screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this is it has been already answered...
[Android front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098729/android-front-camera)