# How to let to run Android app on devices with front camera only?

Tags: android, android-manifest, uses-feature

I'm trying to figure out is there a way to let my app runs on devices with front camera only. Well, I think I should make it through `<uses-feature>` in `AnrdoidManifest.xml`.

I made it like that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

but it doesn't help. I mean I can run it on my device without front-facing camera. But maybe this features don't let users to download an app if their device doesn't have such feature?

If I'm wrong, please tell me the right way to solve my problem.

Regards, Dmitriy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The users won't be able to download it from the **Android Market** if they don't have a front camera thanks to the `uses-feature`. So don't worry about that.

Now, in case someone "**steals**" your **apk**, then you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098729/android-front-camera) to see how you programmatically check for a front camera.

Comment: is that for sure, that this code will prevent downloading from market?

Comment: i mean code from AndroidManifest.xml, not code from link you provided with

Comment: @Dmitriy Yes. It is only the android Market which actually uses the "uses-"feature" option and won't allow users who don't qualify to download your application