# Is it possible to know which camera is currently using in android?

Tags: android

In my application i want to know whether the camera application is On or not and also the type of camera(Front camera or back) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6098729/760489

Answer (score 0):

The [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) class may solve your question. Execute getCameraInfo to get the information and then use [CameraInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html). It has two constants:

```
int CAMERA_FACING_BACK The facing of the camera is opposite to that of the screen.

int CAMERA_FACING_FRONT The facing of the camera is the same as that of the screen.
```

Answer (score 0):

check on

```
Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
```

OR

```
Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
```