# Take photos from front-facing and rear cameras on android 2.2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm designing an app (on version 2.2) that use the camera to capture photos.

I read from http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html that version 2.3 and above have multiple cameras support. But i'm still a bit confused because when the camera is launched, it normally have a button that the user can click to switch between front-facing and rear cameras, right?

or

2.2 doesn't have this switch?

I want the user to be able to use both front and rear cameras. Is it possible on version 2.2 or should I use 2.3 and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 2.2 can only manage rear camera.
For frontal camera you need to upgrade to 2.3+.

```
private int getBestCameraId() {

        PackageManager pm = m_mainThreadContext.getPackageManager();

        try {
            if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Phone has a frontal camera.");
                return Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Phone has only rear camera.");
                return Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                return Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    }

}
```

With this simple function it check whether the phone has a frontal or rear camera, and return the best.
The id returned can be used in the Camera.open(id) to select the desired camera.

If in your Manifest you write:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

and you develop your project with libraries 2.3 (or +), the function i have posted works like a charm!
I've used in a camera project, so trust me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098729/android-front-camera)

For APIs >=9, you can use the [Camera class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) to see if it has more than one camera, and query the CameraInfo

```
getNumberOfCameras

getCameraInfo:
```

And for Android 2.2 and lower versions, supports a single camera in its SDK.