# Fail to connect camera service in front camera?

Tags: java, android, xml

i am using Camera Api in that when ever i lanch app it will show back camera it works fine but when i click front camera button it will get Runtime excetion Fail to connect camera service

```
in  camera = Camera.open(cameraID);

in front camera button code :

if (cameraID == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Front Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                cameraID = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;

            }
            else if (cameraID == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                cameraID = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;

            }

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            finish();

            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Did you add Permission for using camera in Manifest?

Comment: yes i given permission in Manifest file Camera permission

Answer (score 2):

Have you give the permission for front camera:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Check this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829162/failed-to-connect-to-camera-service) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098729/android-front-camera) Once.

Comment: still i get error fail to connect camera service please help me still i get error

Comment: check my edited answer above I have added one more feature auto focus, try to add in your manifest file

Comment: 02-01 15:26:50.199: E/AndroidRuntime(12806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 15:26:50.199: E/AndroidRuntime(12806): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Comment: i am using this permissins in manifest uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> 

      
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: Check this link and check your min sdk version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867830/take-photos-from-front-facing-and-rear-cameras-on-android-2-2

Comment: Try above all links that I have given,I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23769/discussion-between-the-maulik-and-vr-naresh)