# How to use front camera in Xing QR Code scanner libary on android

Tags: java, android

I wish to know how can I use front camera with Xing library on android to scan 2D Qr code . I mean what what code is required ?

Thanks a lot 
Vishal

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you looked? What is your current code like? We need more information if we're going to be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, You'll have to fork the [source](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and replace all camera related code with code that uses the front camera. If you are asking each and every instance where this needs to be done, then it is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Here is a thread that tells you how to use a front camera:

[Android front camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098729/android-front-camera)

The rest you will have to do yourself and you can always come back if you have more specific problems.

Comment: thanks i know rest but wanted to know if it comes with some easier way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

I Would like to Refer you to [Add option to flip image to accommodate front cameras](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=660) that is related to  QR Code and Front Camera issues.